# JTree only allows me to add 1 file

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm trying to make a JTree that replicates the structure of files dropped on it. The problem I'm having is that my code only first file I add. When I try to d&d another file into the tree it is simply ignored. This is the drag & drop functionality:

```
root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Home");
JTree jtree = new JTree(root);


/**
* JScrollPane and other swing code here.
* Try-catch blocks in the code below were
* removed for readability
**/


jtree.setDropTarget(new DropTarget() {
        public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent evt) {
            evt.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
            ArrayList<File> inputFiles = new ArrayList<>();
            inputFiles.addAll((List<File>) evt.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor));
                updateTree(inputFiles);
        }
    });
```

And this is the method I'm using for adding the nodes:

```
private void updateTree(ArrayList<File> inputFiles){

    for(File f: inputFiles){
        String[] filePath = f.getPath().split("\\\\");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = root;
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child;

            for(String g: filePath){
                child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(g);
                node.add(child);
                node = child;
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to notify the model that new nodes have being added

Comment: It's a little annoying as more often the not you're dealing with nodes & not the model :P